# If many Kafka streams updates domain model (a.k.a materialized view)?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have a materialized view that is updated from many streams. **Every one enrich it partially**. Order doesn't matter. Updates comes in not specified time. Is following algorithm is a good approach:

1. Update comes and I check what is stored in materialized view via `get()`, that this is an initial one so enrich and save.
2. Second comes and `get()` shows that partial update exist - add next information
3. ... and I continue with same style

If there is a query/join, object that is stored has a method that shows that the update is not complete `isValid()` that could be used in `KafkaStreams#filter()`.

Could you share please is this a good plan? Is there any pattern in Kafka streams world that handle this case?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your plan looks good , you have the general idea, but you'll have to use the lower Kafka Stream API : [Processor API](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html).

There is a .transform operator that allow you to access a KeyValueStatestore, inside this operation implementation you are free to decide if you current aggregated value is valid or not.

Therefore send it downstream or returning null waiting for more information.